# Eclipse: Hover not working for warning and errors

Tags: java, eclipse, hover

I'm using Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800 not that it matter because no matter which version I use, I have no tooltips when I hover over an error or warning.

The only plugin I have installed is "Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0" which came I think preinstalled with my eclipse installation.

I also checked the value of my Windows 10 installation "MouseHoverTime" registry key (at 30)

Finally, I've also restored to default the settings at Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Hovers.

[edit]: I have noticed that the message which I'm supposed to see in the tooltips I'm trying to enable are written in the status bar, I want them in the hover tho

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to your answer?

Comment: It's just an observation, I want the tooltips to come out when I hover over warnings/errors in my code

Comment: If a Java file contains only `{`, `Syntax error on token "{"` will be shown in the status bar when hovering `{`, right?

Comment: @M.Joe: What is checked in the Default Hovers option?  With Neon (though I realize that you said Oxygen) I show checked: `Combined Hover`, `Externalized String`, `Javadoc`, and `Source`.

Comment: @howlger Yes, I see  `Syntax error on token "{", delete this token.`. @Paul I see thoses checked and they all have a key modifier except `Combined Hover`

Comment: @M.Joe Can you observe the same behavior when you switch to a new workspace?

Comment: @howlger yes doesnt matter which workspace of I create a new one. Also, I've got the same problem in Spring Tool Suite (which is built on Eclipse).

Comment: @M.Joe I would like to see a screenshot with the error displayed in the status bar.

Comment: @howlger Here is it https://i.imgur.com/ie8KCPf.png

Comment: @M.Joe Did I miss something, or is the error and the mouse pointer missing in the screenshot?

Comment: @howgler ? bottom left corner, there the java error that I'm supposed to see in a tooltip when I hover over it (in the code)